# Dataset to an array of objects in Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a input object of two array

```
payload 

columns:["col1" , "col2","col3"],
data: ["col1value1","col2value1" , "col1value3"] ,
      ["col1value2","col2value2" , "col1value2"]
```

Now I want to convert this two array of objects like below
output = [];

```
[
  { col1: 'col1value1', col2: 'col2value1', col3: col1value3},
  { col1: 'col1value2', col2: 'col2value2', col3: col1value2}
]
```

trying to use reduce or other methods -- but not getting it - have to hard code index of column in data array . is there any better and fast way? in which it will done without hard coding the column names.

currently doing like

```
const indexofCol1= this.payload.columns.indexOf["col1"]
```

then using that index to map in `data` array to get all the values -- which is not a good way .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries). Since you want to map your `data` arrays to objects, you can first call `.map()` on it. For each inner array (detonated as `row`), you can build an object using `Object.fromEntries()`. The `fromEntries()` method takes an array of `[[key, value], ...]` pairs, which you can construct mapping your `cols` array, where each key is a value from `cols` and each value is the associated item in your current `row` array.

See example below:

```js
const cols = ["col1" , "col2","col3"];
const data = [["col1value1","col2value1" , "col1value3"], ["col1value2","col2value2" , "col1value2"]];

const res = data.map(row => Object.fromEntries(
  cols.map((key, i) => [key, row[i]])
));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;} /* ignore */
```

If you cannot support `Object.fromEntries()`, you can use a more browser-friendly version of the above which uses [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/assign) and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const cols = ["col1" , "col2","col3"];
const data = [["col1value1","col2value1" , "col1value3"], ["col1value2","col2value2" , "col1value2"]];

const res = data.map(row => Object.assign({},
  ...cols.map((key, i) => ({[key]: row[i]}))
));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;} /* ignore */
```

Comment: getting issues with .fromEntries , as it does not exist in Object constructor

Comment: @Shaswata Could be a compatibility issues, I'll update with a more browser-friendly version.

Comment: @Shaswata I've updated my answer to use `Object.assign()` in the second code-snippet

Comment: const res = this.payload.data.map(row => Object.assign(
        ...this.payload.columns.map((key, i) => ({[key]: row[i]}))
      ));
getting error in columns map -- expected atleast 1 argument - got 0

Comment: @Shaswata my bad, I sometimes forget how strict TS can be. I've edited the second code snippet which should fix that error (added `{},` after Object.assign)